# Usage of CSS selectors for the next available element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have my html tree this way

```
<input type = "checkbox" style = "display:none" id = "select">
<label for = "select" id = 'click'>
  click
</label>
<div class = 'next'>    
</div>
```

Now how is that i could style for the div 'next' when the checkbox is checked using the selectors in css

i tried it this way but it didn't work

```
#click:checked + .next{
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
#select:checked ~ .next {
    color: blue;
}
```

It's not the *click* element that gets the value of checked, it's the input, which has id *select*.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .next{
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33XU8/)

The `div` doesnt appear directly following the checkbox which is what the `+` adjacent selector considers, using `~` will rectify this. Also, apply the `:checked` selector to the input not its label.

[More on the `+` adjacency selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

> This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the
>   specified element that *immediately* follows the former specified
>   element.

[More on the `~` general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

Comment: @user3464111 - great!